# generic parameter type which accepts a Future[String] and String

Tags: scala

I am in need of defining a function

```
def acceptFutureOfStringOrString(param: T) = ???
```

where T is a generic type that can accept both Future[String] and String. Please let me know how should I define the type. Thanks

Comment: What is the use case here? How are you going to call this function and what is the result type? Why not write it as two polymorphic methods rather than using a type parameter?

Comment: First of all, this design choice of accepting `String` or a `Future[String]` really scares me. If you really want to do this you can either use union types of Scala 3 or use Either and pass in a `Left[String]` etc. but as Tim suggested I think there is a deeper issue here

Comment: As the logic inside function remains functionally same i.e the parameter is going to be used the same way, I am trying to not define polymorphic functions as it would be duplication except for parameter type.

Comment: Why not make it String and then call it from within any of the Future-transformations? (as an example: future.map(acceptString))

Comment: @ApprenticeWST "As the logic inside function remains functionally same..." care to share what that logic _is_? I am having a trouble imagining things that you can do with a `String` and `Future[String]`, but not with other types. I mean, you can print it, I suppose, but if that's _all_ your function does, why not make it `Any`?

Comment: thanks all for answers. The right answer is to do map on Future and then utilise the String within Future[String] as someone else as well suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function taking "something that has a `String`":

```
def accept[F[_]](param: F[String]) = ???
```

Of course, you can't quite *work* with that. But since you've mentioned cats, you can do e.g.

```
def accept[F[_]: Monad](param: F[String]) = ???
```

This will allow you to call `map`/`flatMap`, i.e. chain computations on `F[String]`. You can call it with raw values by doing `accept[cats.Id]("foo")`. That is actually fairly common on FP side of things, though you lose Future-specific things like ability to use `Await.result` or handle errors.

---

If you really want to accept *only* string or Future of string, you can use `Either`:

```
def accept(param: Either[String, Future[String]]) = ???
```

or Either2K, another cats thing:

```
def accept(param: Either2K[Id, Future, String]) = ???
```

If you're using Scala 3, you can use a union type:

```
def accept(param: String | Future[String]) = ???
```

If you're stuck to Scala 2, you can also use a custom data type with an implicit conversion to avoid wrapping at the call site:

```scala
sealed trait Thingie
case class OfString(s: String) extends Thingie
case class OfFuture(fs: Future[String]) extends Thingie

object Thingie {
  implicit def fromString(s: String): Thingie = OfString(s)
  implicit def fromFutureString(fs: Future[String]): Thingie = OfFuture(fs)
}

def accept(param: Thingie) = ???

// Will look seamless
accept("foo")
accept(Future.successful("bar"))
```

---

Which one is best for you, I can't tell without a context. If you can't make `F[_]` variant work, stick with Either or union for utility methods; the implicit conversion thing should be reserved for fancy DSLs and even there used sparingly.

Comment: One more option – just defined too damn functions :) `def foo(f: Future[String]) = ??? ; def foo(s: String) = foo(Future(s))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to restrict the types that can be passed to your function, use a typeclass:

```
sealed trait AllowableType[T]

implicit object AllowString extends AllowableType[String] {}
implicit object AllowFutureString extends AllowableType[Future[String]] {}

def acceptFutureOfStringOrString[T: AllowableType](param: T) = ???
```

If you want to do some processing with the values that depends on the type, add the processing fuctions as methods to the `trait` and implement them in each `implicit object`.

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation of Tim's answer,
I can conjure something like this, but it's a really weird way to do things.

```
  sealed trait IsWithinBounds[P, T]
  object IsWithinBounds {
    implicit def Future[T]: IsWithinBounds[Future[T], T] = new IsWithinBounds[Future[T], T] {}
    implicit def String: IsWithinBounds[String, String]  = new IsWithinBounds[String, String] {}
  }

  def t[T](param: T)(implicit ev: T IsWithinBounds String): Any = ???

  t("some string")        //ok
  t(Future("some future string")) //ok
  t(42)              //compile error
```

Answer (score -2):

thanks all for answers. The right answer is to do map on Future and then utilise the String within Future[String] as someone else as well suggested.

Comment: This means that the code will have different behaviour in the two cases. But you were asked about this right at the start, and you said that "the parameter is going to be used the same way" which is clearly not the case. And the question clearly states that you want a single function with a parameter of two types. Three people wasted time answering the wrong question because of this. Doing `map` on the `Future` is the obvious thing to do, but did not answer the question you asked. So the next time you ask a question please provide accurate information so that time is not wasted. Thanks.